# Get negative numbers from expression

Tags: c#, regex, shunting-yard

I'm trying to separate the tokens on a string expression. The expression looks like this:

```
-1-2+-3
```

This is the regex I'm using:

```
[\d\.]+|[-][\d\.]+|\+|\-|\*|\/|\^|\(|\)
```

This brings me these matches:

```
-1
-2
+
-3
```

I was expecting:

```
-1
-
2
+
-3
```

Any ideas how can I distinct negative numbers from operators?

Comment: Regular expressions are not a good fit for this problem. You need to create a simple stateful parser.

Comment: This issue might be too difficult to solve with Regex alone, a full parser (that keeps track of state) may be required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you could try this one; it makes use of a look-behind:

```
((?<=\d)[+*\/^()-]|\-?[\d.]+)
```

I tested it [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/mU4zN1).

Basically, makes sure that there is a number before the operator to decide what to match. So, if there is a digit before the operator, treat the operator alone, otherwise, combine the minus with the digit.

EDIT: Separated the brackets from the lot, just in case ([demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/iL0bG4)):

```
((?<=\d)[+*\/^-]|[()]|\-?[\d.]+)
```

Answer (score 1):

This pattern should do what you're looking for:

```
^(?:(?<num>-?[\d\.]+)(?:(?<op>[-+*/^])|$))+$
```

For example:

```
var input = "-1-2+-3";
var pattern = @"^(?:(?<num>-?[\d\.]+)(?:(?<op>[-+*/^])|$))+$";
var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
var results =
    from Group g in match.Groups.Cast<Group>().Skip(1)
    from Capture c in g.Captures
    orderby c.Index
    select c.Value;
```

Will produce:

```
-1 
- 
2 
+ 
-3
```